# Which is better for performance, selecting all the columns or select only the required columns while performng join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am been asked to do performance tuning of a SQL Server query which has so many joins in it.

For example

```
LEFT JOIN 
    vw_BILLABLE_CENSUS_R CEN ON DE.Client = CEN.Client
                             AND CAL.REPORTING_MONTH = CEN.REPORTING_MONTH
```

There are almost 25 columns present in `vw_Billing_Cenus_R` but we wanted to use only 3 of them. So I wanted to know instead of selecting all the columns from the view or table, if I only select those columns which are required and then perform join like this

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Column_1], [Column_2], [Column_3] 
           FROM vw_BILLABLE_CENSUS_R) CEN ON DE.Client = CEN.Client
                                          AND CAL.REPORTING_MONTH = CEN.REPORTING_MONTH
```

So Will this improve the performance or not?

Comment: Why not compare the execution plans to check this yourself?

Comment: Selecting from a `VIEW` isn't the same as selecting from a `TABLE`.  A `VIEW` can consist of many joins to multiple tables itself.

Answer (score 5):

The important part is the columns you are actually using on the outmost `SELECT`, not the ones to are selecting to join. The SQL Server engine is smart enough to realize that he does not need to retrieve all columns from the referenced table (or view) if he doesn't need them.

So the following 2 queries *should* yield the exact same query execution plan:

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn
FROM
    MyTable AS A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            OtherTable AS B) AS X ON A.SomeColumn = X.SomeColumn

SELECT
    A.SomeColumn
FROM
    MyTable AS A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            B.SomeColumn
        FROM
            OtherTable AS B) AS X ON A.SomeColumn = X.SomeColumn
```

The difference would be if you actually use the selected column (in a conditional where or actually retrieving the value), as in here:

```
SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    X.* -- * has all X columns
FROM
    MyTable AS A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            B.*
        FROM
            OtherTable AS B) AS X ON A.SomeColumn = X.SomeColumn


SELECT
    A.SomeColumn,
    X.* -- * has only X's SomeColumn
FROM
    MyTable AS A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            B.SomeColumn
        FROM
            OtherTable AS B) AS X ON A.SomeColumn = X.SomeColumn
```

Comment: Execution plan remains the same but the physical and logical reads differ. In the second query you will notice that the physical and logical reads will be less

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use this approach:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    vw_BILLABLE_CENSUS_R CEN ON DE.Client = CEN.Client
                             AND CAL.REPORTING_MONTH = CEN.REPORTING_MONTH
```

than this

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Column_1], [Column_2], [Column_3] 
           FROM vw_BILLABLE_CENSUS_R) CEN ON DE.Client = CEN.Client
                                          AND CAL.REPORTING_MONTH = CEN.REPORTING_MONTH
```

Since in this case:

1. you make your query simpler,
2. you does not have to rely on query optimizer smartness and expect that it will eliminate unnecessary columns and rows
3. finally, you can select as many columns in the outer SELECT as necessary without using derived tables techniques.

In some cases, derived tables are welcome, when you want to eliminate duplicates in a table you want to join on a fly, but, imho, not in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many records are stored, but generally it will improve performance.
In this case read @LukStorms ' comments, I think he is right

Comment: But he's joining a view, not a table.   I doubt it would help in such case.

Comment: @LukStorms you are right.
Anyway it is always better move less data as possible

Comment: Well, comparing the excecution plan of both versions should give him an answer about which is faster.

Comment: If it's a viiew that only selects from 1 table then he could change the join to link to the table itself, and use the criteria from the view in that subquery.

Comment: Another thing, he talks about multiple joins.  if some of those joins are to the same view/table then he could use a CTE. And join that CTE multiple times.